# Dom Element not being assigned value

Tags: javascript, dom

Could anyone explain why currentOperationScreen isn't showing/being assigned 5? console.log says numbr = 5.

Thanks!

```
let currentOperationScreen = document.getElementById('currentOperationScreen');
currentOperationScreen = '';
console.log(currentOperationScreen);

function appendToDisplay(numbr) {
    console.log(numbr);
    console.log(currentOperationScreen);
    if (numbr === '0' && currentOperationScreen.textContent === '') {
        return;
    }
    currentOperationScreen.textContent += numbr;
    console.log(currentOperationScreen);
}

dataButton = document.querySelectorAll('.data-number');
dataButton.forEach((button) => 
    button.addEventListener('click', () => appendToDisplay(button.textContent)))
```

Comment: after this line `currentOperationScreen = '';`, `currentOperationScreen` is no longer a Dom element. it becomes an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

javascript has auto conversion., which can compare strings with numbers.
you use === instead of ==. if you want to use === initialize currentOperationScreen with 0 not '0'
more details here [MDN Auto Conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality#comparison_with_type_conversion)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="currentOperationScreen bg-green-400"></div>
        <button class="data-number px-5 py-3 bg-green-400 rounded"> click </button> 
        <button class="data-number px-5 py-3 bg-green-400 rounded"> click </button> 
        <button class="data-number px-5 py-3 bg-green-400 rounded"> click </button> 
        <script>
            let currentOperationScreen = document.getElementById('currentOperationScreen');
            currentOperationScreen = 0;
           
            function appendToDisplay(numbr) {
                if (numbr === 0 && currentOperationScreen === 0) {
                    return;
                }
                currentOperationScreen += numbr;
                console.log(currentOperationScreen);
            }
    
            dataButton = document.querySelectorAll('.data-number');
            dataButton.forEach((button) => 
            // add number to function appendToDisplay
            button.addEventListener('click', () => appendToDisplay(5)))
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[for my code result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEnEV.png)

is this what you mean?

Comment: Hi!  Great job with this answer.  Can you please modify the answer to use proper punctuation and grammar?  As it is, it's a bit difficult to understand your answer.  The more clear you can be, the easier it will be for others to understand you.  Keep up the great work!